# HIVE SERDE REGEX: Output format - want to use only few of the output Strings

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive, hiveql

the input file is as follows

eno::ename::dept::sal

101::emp1::comp1::2800000

201::emp2::comp2::2800000

301::emp3::comp3::3400000

401::emp4::comp4::3600000

501::emp5::comp5::400000

```
>create table emp(ename string,edept string)
> row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'           
> WITH SERDEPROPERTIES(                                                         
> "input.regex"="^([^\\::]+)\\::([^\\::]+)\\::([^\\::]+)\\::([^\\::]+)$",           
> "output.format.string"="%2$s%3$s")                                            
> ;
>load data local inpath '/home/cloudera/test/emp.txt' into table emp;
```

i want to pull only the 2nd and 3rd literals into the table. So using "output.format.string"="%2$s%3$s" - is this right way  ?

But my table gets loaded with eno & ename only.

Answer (score 1):

The Hive table has only two columns but regex captures four groups, thus the additional groups are just ignored.

You can use the following expression.

```
"input.regex"="^[^\\::]+\\::([^\\::]+)\\::([^\\::]+)\\::[^\\::]+$"
```

You get the following output.

```
emp.ename   emp.edept
emp1        comp1
emp2        comp2
emp3        comp3
emp4        comp4
emp5        comp5
```